# get the length from last 2 columns in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I am trying to get the inside values only from the given table, I am supposed to write a for loop but I am very new in python and I am stuck. It is not printing the length of th

```
gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       inside        1     6

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix       7    29

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       outside      30    86

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix      87   109

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       inside      110   121

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     122   144

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       outside     145   158

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     159   178

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       inside      179   198

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     199   221

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       outside     222   244

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     245   267

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       inside      268   286

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     287   309

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       outside     310   328

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       TMhelix     329   351

gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1|     TMHMM2.0       inside      352   374

    lin = process.stdout.readlines()

    for line in lin:
        if line.startswith('gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1| TMHMM2.0 inside'):

            trimed_line = lin.strip()
            elements = trimed_line.split(' ') 
            last_second, last_one = elements[-2], elements[-1]

            # use len() to check the length 
            len_of_last_second_column = len(last_second)
            len_of_last_column = len(last_one)

#       print len_of_last_second_column 
            print len_of_last_column
```

it is not giving me the output length

Comment: please show us where you are stuck. What is the code you have written so far? what exactly does not work? Do you get an error, if so which one? Is the output not what you expected - if so what is the output.

Comment: Is your data in a file or something else? Can you give us some piece of code or even some more details.

Comment: I have to use a tool to get this output I have written, from that I have to fetch the information for "inside" "outside" or "TMhelix" . I have to run a for loop searching for the inside length,

Comment: I don't know how to run the for loop. like how can I get the last 2 columns and add it up.

Comment: I have attached the code, please have a look.

Comment: You can use the Python csv module with the `|` delimiter. Much easier.

Comment: I have never used Python csv, as I am very new, but I am supposed to get this by writing a code on my own. That is  the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv:

```
import csv
with open (fn) as csv_txt:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_txt, delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True):
        print row
```

Prints:

```
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 inside 1 6']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 TMhelix 7 29']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 outside 30 86']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 TMhelix 87 109']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 inside 110 121']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 TMhelix 122 144']
['gi', '564120226', 'gb', 'AHB72725.1', 'TMHMM2.0 outside 145 158']
....
```

Then just take the length of the element in question.

Answer (score -1):

difference = 0
for line in lin:

```
if line.startswith('gi|564120226|gb|AHB72725.1| TMHMM2.0    inside'):

    elements = line.split('\t')

    last_second, last_one = elements[-2], elements[-1]
    last_one= last_one.split()      
    diff=int(last_one[1])-int(last_one[0])
    print "diff", diff      
    difference=diff+difference+1
print "total inside length", difference
```

This is the answer I came up with, and it worked, thank you all for helping me.

Comment: Too specific to your test case, does not match the "generic heading" of the problem.